# Capacity Management database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am designing database using Microsoft Access for capacity management. I have different types of equipment and need to track the power usage by every month. For instance, I have HVAC system and Chiller System. Withing each system there are different equipments like AHU_1, AHU_2 ,AHU_3, MAU_1, MAU_2 and etc in HVAC system and CHWP_1, CHWP_2, CWP_1, CWP_2 and etc in Chiller system.

I need to track the power or usage by every month. For each system i have separate tables containing their respective equipments. What will be suitable way to track the usage? This is what I'm planning to do which I believe there are three options as in the picture below:

Creating a main table called Chiller_usage Table which will have all the equipments and dates with usage value. The problem i see is that it will has repetitive of each equipments due to dates and the pro is not many tables.[image: Chiller_usage Table]

Creating each equipment table which will have dates and usage. The problem is I have around 60 to 70 equipments with 5 different major systems and will lead to mass amount of table which will be very difficult when making queries and reports. [image: equip_usage Table]
Creating date table with equipments and usage value. This looks promising for now because i will have few table initially and as times goes on there will be 12 tables each year which is alot in the future.
[image: date_table]

What I'm thinking of is the first option since it is easy to manage when making custom queries because I need to perform calculation in terms of costing, usage analysis of each equipment with graphs and etc. But that i believe will be clumsy due to repetitive name of equipments due to variable dates. Is there any other viable options? Thank you.

Comment: Option 1 is more normalized structure. Repetition of equipment identifier is not a problem, this is normal. Your question is about design, not programming and not really suited to SO.

Comment: I see. Anyway thanks for the input man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you need to store monthly energy usage for each piece of equipment.  Normalize the tables.  neither the person entering the data or the manager asking for reports needs to see the complexity of the underlying tables.  The person entering the data sees both a form for adding systems/equipment and a form for entering energy usage per equipment per month.  The manager sees a report with just the information he wants like energy costs per a system per a year.  The normalized tables can be recombined into human readable tables with queries.  Access trys to make making the forms and reports as simple as clicking on those appropriate queries and then clicking on create form/report.  In practice some assembly is required.  Behind the scenes the forms put the correct data in the correct tables and the report shows only the data the manager wants.  For instance. here is a normalized table structure based on the data you provided and some assumptions:
[image]

The tables are normalized and have the relationships shown.  Beneath there is a query to show the total power each system uses between any two dates such as for a yearly report.  So data looking like this:
[image]

is turned into this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks man. I actually thought of doing the similar stuff since i made a warehouse management system using this method. I thought maybe there should be some other way to optimize. I'll mark this as answer! Thank you. @mazoula